# Why is IE8 developer tool showing wrong line no for object expected error?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, firefox, internet-explorer-8

I am facing a strange javascript object expected error in IE8? On IE Developer tool the error shown as

```
Object expected  products.aspx?productid=127, line 234066871 character 5
```

There is only around 350 lines in the rendered html source. How to find the correct source of error.

**Edit:** There are following includes in the file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/store/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/store/Scripts/jquery.imgareaselect.pack-0.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/store/Scripts/thickbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/store/Scripts/jquery.tooltip.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/store/Scripts/jquery.query-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/store/Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/store/Scripts/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/store/Scripts/jquery.jcarousel.pack.js"></script>
```

And a call to Initialize.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('Product1$ctl00$ScriptManager1', 'form1', ['Product1$ctl00$updatepanel01',''], [], [], 90, '');
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: What you have given will not help us solve the problem.

Comment: My problem is that why the IE Developer tool showing wrong line no.

Comment: You can narrow it down by posting only the JavaScript calls in the page.

Comment: @Amitabh: the error is strange indeed, but it's going to be very tricky for anyone to have a stab at the answer if you don't show us your code or link to the page.

Comment: Rule #1: never trust the line number in IE error messages.

Comment: if you have lots and lots of different js files/HTML text, It'll factor these into the line count as it got there. Say for example you have a PHP include... That could add 1000 lines to when the call to this function was made...

Comment: @Glycerine: PHP includes are never seen by the browser (unless your web server is misconfigured).

Comment: Typically an experienced developer will be able to quickly identifier all of the possible reference errors in a large chuck of code within a very short time.

Comment: @Marcel - Totally dude but if your PHP spits out HTML or anything, they line numbers of your js/HTML will not match that of your IDE. Couple of times I've had a 'o_O Eh?' moment with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit -

*@Glycerine: I have added some source code which I think is called at the time of PageLoad.*

Can you see why this happens? I bet if you count the lines in each of your libs... You'll reach that random number.

if you code does not rely on these libs, place your lines of code before these script tags. and your line number will change to something more realistic...

**Again. When JS counts lines to the error occurrence, its not just the one file its looking at.**

---

Totally need more dude. But uber guess would be:

The function called has an optional object you send to it as an argument. Leaving this empty on other browsers is OK, but IE can be strict.

Ensure if your calling the function and it requires an arugment - if you intend not to send anything to it send a null/empty/0 value ANYHTING you want you can check against to make sure you dont want it. This MAY fix whatever problem you have. Or maybe not. Or maybe your IE could be broken - or you havent added your javascript. Anything could be happening... Send us some source?

Comment: I have added some source code which I think is called at the time of PageLoad.

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that one of your script tags is dependent on another one. Try examining the dependencies of each script and see if you need to reorder the script tags.